# cakephp2 return one random record from database

Tags: mysql, random, controller, cakephp-2.2

I am experiencing a problem with my find to return a random record. 
The thing is, the condition is not working for some reason.

DB:

```
quotes: 
        title (varchar255)
        content (varchar255)
        published (tinyint(1) NULL default = 0)


$random_quotes = $this->Quote->find('all',array('condition'=>array('Quote.published'=>1),'order'=>array('rand()'),'limit'=>1));
```

It returns 1 quote no mather what published = 0/1. It does not use the condition at all in the find. Have tried a find first as well. still.. published 0/1 does not mather. It returns a record no mather what.

Anyone know why this is happening??

I only have 2 quotes in the db now, and both = published = 0, still the find returns a result.

Thanks for any help on this!!!

-Tom

Answer (score 0):

The condition option should be conditions (plural), otherwise it queries with no conditions.